# Is $\phi: L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}\to \mathbb{R}, \phi(u,v)=(\zeta u, v)_{L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

How do I show that the bilinear continuous functional

$\phi: L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}\to \mathbb{R}, \phi(u,v)=(\zeta u, v)_{L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}}$

is continuous?

I need to prove that:
$\exists m>0 $ such that
$$|\phi(u,v)| \leq m {||u||}_{L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}} {||v||}_{L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}}$$
$\forall u, v \in L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}$ 
Where $\zeta $ is an operator.

I tried to show, but I don't know how. Is it true the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if $u, v \in L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}$ ?

Comment: Is the operator $\zeta$ continuous? What is $L^2(\Omega)^{d\times d}$?

Comment: Yes, $\zeta$ is continuous.
$ L^2 (\Omega)^{d \times d} = \{ u |u = (u_{ij}) \in L^2 (\Omega) , 1\leq i,j \leq d\} $

$L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert spaces

Comment: The space $H=L_2(\Omega)^{d\times d}$ with the operation $(u,v)=\sum_{ij}\int_\Omega u_{ij}\overline{v_{ij}}$ is a Hilbert space. The rest is the problem is the usual Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunyakovsky inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$|(\zeta u,v)|\leq\|\zeta u\|\|v\|$ by Cauchy inequality, then using the boundedness of $\zeta$, one has $\|\zeta u\|\leq\|\zeta\|\|u\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!